# wxWidgets: How to make a gui without passing control to it?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have made a simple score4 game. It was a project so I made a CLI IO system.

Wanting to upgrade in the furure I made the whole IO Interface (move choosing, board show) a bunch of virtual functions in a class. So I made the CLI Interface just by implementing those functions with iostream usage. I initialize this Interface like this:

```
IOInterface *ii = new IOConsoleInterface();
```

Now I want to make wxWidgets Interface of the game and run it with a -gui switch. I made the frames quite easily but now that I want to finally connect the pieces, when I initialize the GUI it enters an infinite loop and doesnt return to the Score4 game loop.

The game loop calls ii functions so i dont need the control in the wxWidgets. I want it just to be there and do the stuff it is ordered to do by the game loop.

thank you in advance

Edit: The Score4 wasn't a wx Application. I just want to apply some wxGUI classes to it.

Edit2: The game loop code:

"ii" is InputInterface, an object that takes information
like move and play-again answer

"oi" is OutpuInterface, an object that draws the board and
tells the player that it is his turn

```
void Mechanics::gameLoop(){

bool newGame = true;
int gameCounter = 0;

while(newGame){

    short choice = 0;
    short turn;
    gameCounter++;

    currentPlayer = decideStart(gameCounter);
    board.clear();
    oi->refreshTable(board, p1,p2); 


    for (turn = 1; turn <= ROWS*COLS; turn++){

        oi->playerPrompt(currentPlayer);

        do{
            if (currentPlayer->isAI == 0)
                choice = ii->getPlayersMove(currentPlayer);
            else{
                GameInstance gi = exportGameInstance();
                choice = currentPlayer->chooseMove(gi);     // AI's movement
            }

        } while (!(board.checkMoveValidity(choice)));   //breaks when move is valid--> when condition is >0

        board.move(choice,currentPlayer);

        oi->moveAnimation(choice,currentPlayer);

        oi->refreshTable(board, p1,p2); 

        if (board.winConditionCheck(currentPlayer))
            break;

        changeCurrentPlayer();
    }

    if (turn > ROWS*COLS)       //draw
        oi->draw_conclusion();
    else
        oi->win_loss_conclusion(true,currentPlayer);


    newGame = ii->newGamePrompt();
}

    delete ii;
    delete oi;
                    // GAME ENDS HERE
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the event loop in the GUI application, there is no (reasonable) way around that. So while you can initialize wxWidgets without entering the event loop using e.g. `wxEntryStart()`, you still do need to run it later.

If you want to have both console and GUI interfaces the best would be to run the event loop in both cases, except you'd run your own event loop in the former case and wx one in the latter.

Comment: There is a (maybe unreasonable) way around it… move the console game's event loop into a separate thread, and use a socket or a pair of pipes (or etc) to allow the game logic's event loop to send messages to (and receive messages from) the GUI event loop, the same way it does with stdin and stdout now.  Not the easiest thing to do, but possible.